# How do you change App Transport Security Settings based on the build configuration?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I have an app with multiple build configurations. If the selected configuration is Debug, I want *NSAllowsArbitraryLoads* key in the `Info.plist` file to be set as YES, else I want it to be set as NO.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found requires the use of [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html):

In your project settings, select Build Phase > click + to add a new run script build phase.

Name the phase "App Transport Security".
Paste the following script:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; 
then 
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads false" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}" 
else 
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads true" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}" 
fi
```